# How do I get the ripple effect work in Varlet UI?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ripple-effect

I am using `Vue v3.2.20` with `Varlet UI v1.25.0` and `Bootstrap 5` in my project. So far everything worked well, but I can't get the ripple effect working anywhere, even on the buttons. I don't get any errors or warnings in the console. A simple button declaration like this:

```
<var-button type="primary">Add</var-button>
```

shows up a default button without the ripple effect. I imported the framework in `main.js` as so:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

import Varlet from '@varlet/ui'
import '@varlet/ui/es/style.js'

createApp(App).use(router).use(Varlet).mount('#app')
```

Also, I tried to add the ripple effect manually on a div per [this documentation](https://varlet.gitee.io/varlet-ui/#/en-US/ripple), still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared that Varlet UI worked differently on mobile and desktop environments, so all I needed to do in order to get the ripple effect work on desktop was to install the touch emulator:

```
npm i @varlet/touch-emulator
```

as per [the guide](https://varlet.gitee.io/varlet-ui/#/en-US/browserAdaptation)